# Why did Rocky tell Adonis who won the secret 3rd fight?

Tags: creed

At this point in *Creed*, Rocky had not yet decided to train Adonis. In fact, they had only just met and Rocky was surprised that Adonis even knew of the 3rd, secret fight between him and Apollo Creed. Yet he answered the question when asked. Why? Did he answer honestly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rocky has always been a grounded character.  Honest, straight-forward, he shows fear and passion and love.  There's no reason to believe Rocky would lie to Adonis, and there's no reason to believe Rocky wouldn't answer that question.  It would be out-of-character for him to be dishonest or deceitful.

Comment: I agree with most of your assertions about Rocky's character, and i agree that he would not lie to Adonis. However, he did withhold information about his diagnosis, so I think it's within his character to not provide an answer. e.g. He could have said, "I won't say who won the fight," or, "That was between me and Apollo, and I'll take that to my grave."

Comment: I think he kept that info about his diagnosis secret from Adonis only because he didn't want to disrupt his training.  At the point in time with which this question refers, Rocky had no reason to withhold information from the son of one of his best friends.  Just my opinion.